# SVG Fill path dynamic with PHP

Tags: php, svg

I need the 80% fill path in the svg to be filled dynamically with PHP Code. Could someone help me to create this?

```html
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px;">
  <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.4</desc>
  <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <filter id="inner-shadow-g1">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="offset-blur" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse"></feComposite>
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.2" result="color"></feFlood>
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow"></feComposite>
      <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path fill="#fadf50" stroke="none" d="M103.125,120L75,120A75,75,0,0,1,225,120L196.875,120A46.875,46.875,0,0,0,103.125,120Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" filter="url(#inner-shadow-g1)"></path>
  <path
    fill="#00c256"
    stroke="none"
    d="M103.125,120L75,120A75,75,0,0,1,210.67627457812105,75.91610607806453L187.92267161132565,92.44756629879032A46.875,46.875,0,0,0,103.125,120Z"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
    filter="url(#inner-shadow-g1)"
  ></path>
  <text
    x="150"
    y="23.4375"
    text-anchor="middle"
    font-family="sans-serif"
    font-size="15px"
    stroke="none"
    fill="#00c256"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; fill-opacity: 1;"
    font-weight="bold"
    fill-opacity="1"
  >
    <tspan dy="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></tspan>
  </text>
  <text
    x="150"
    y="117.64705882352942"
    text-anchor="middle"
    font-family="Arial"
    font-size="23px"
    stroke="none"
    fill="#00c256"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 23px; font-weight: bold; fill-opacity: 1;"
    font-weight="bold"
    fill-opacity="1"
  >
    <tspan dy="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">80</tspan>
  </text>
  <text
    x="150"
    y="134.18552036199097"
    text-anchor="middle"
    font-family="Arial"
    font-size="10px"
    stroke="none"
    fill="#00c256"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; fill-opacity: 1;"
    font-weight="normal"
    fill-opacity="1"
  >
    <tspan dy="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">%</tspan>
  </text>
  <text
    x="89.0625"
    y="134.18552036199097"
    text-anchor="middle"
    font-family="Arial"
    font-size="10px"
    stroke="none"
    fill="#00c256"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; fill-opacity: 1;"
    font-weight="normal"
    fill-opacity="1"
  >
    <tspan dy="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">0</tspan>
  </text>
  <text
    x="210.9375"
    y="134.18552036199097"
    text-anchor="middle"
    font-family="Arial"
    font-size="10px"
    stroke="none"
    fill="#00c256"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; fill-opacity: 1;"
    font-weight="normal"
    fill-opacity="1"
  >
    <tspan dy="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">100</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: It's helpful to format code with proper indentation – this is more readable for others than a huge block of text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to replace the paths I've commented out with the next 2 pasths in my example.

What I've done: instead of paths you need to fill I'm using a simple arc with a very wide stroke. Now you can use stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset to set the percent of the chart.

As you can see `stroke-dasharray="188.522"` where 188.522 is the total length of the path. In order to get the total length you can use math or you can use javascript and the method `getTotalLength`.

As for the `stroke-dashoffset="37.7"` where 37.7 = the_total_length_of_the_path * (100 - 80)/100 = 188.522 * .2

In PHP you'll need to replace 37.7 with the calculated value.

```html
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px;">
  <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.4</desc>
  <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <filter id="inner-shadow-g1">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="offset-blur" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse"></feComposite>
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.2" result="color"></feFlood>
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow"></feComposite>
      <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <!--<path fill="#fadf50" stroke="none" d="M103.125,120L75,120A75,75,0,0,1,225,120L196.875,120A46.875,46.875,0,0,0,103.125,120Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" filter="url(#inner-shadow-g1)"></path>
  <path fill="#00c256" stroke="none" d="M103.125,120L75,120A75,75,0,0,1,210.67627457812105,75.91610607806453L187.92267161132565,92.44756629879032A46.875,46.875,0,0,0,103.125,120Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" filter="url(#inner-shadow-g1)"></path>-->


  
  <path d="M90,120A60,60 0 0 1 210 120" fill="none" stroke="#fadf50" stroke-width="30"  />
  <path d="M90,120A60,60 0 0 1 210 120" fill="none" stroke="#00c256" stroke-width="30" stroke-dasharray="188.522" stroke-dashoffset="37.7"  /> 
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

the OP is asking:

> How can set the size of the svg?i want to make the above svg smaller in size

You need to:

1. remove `height="100%" width="100%"` from your code
2. use a viewBox attribute. In this case I'll be using `viewBox="75 45 150 92"`
3. now you can set the width of the svg element to what you need. You can do it using a presentational attribute: `<svg width="200"` or you can do it in css: `svg{width:200px}` You don't need to set a `height`.

```css
svg{border:solid; width:200px}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="75 45 150 92" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px;">
  <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.4</desc>
  <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <filter id="inner-shadow-g1">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="offset-blur" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse"></feComposite>
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.2" result="color"></feFlood>
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow"></feComposite>
      <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
    </filter>
  </defs>


  <path d="M90,120A60,60 0 0 1 210 120" fill="none" stroke="#fadf50" stroke-width="30"  />
  <path id="kk" d="M90,120A60,60 0 0 1 210 120" fill="none" stroke="#00c256" stroke-width="30" stroke-dasharray="188.522" stroke-dashoffset="37.7"  /> 
</svg>
```

In order to know the values to use for the viewBox I've wrapped the shapes used for the chart in a `<g>` element and I've used the `getBBox()` method to get the bounding box of the `<g>` (the smallest rectangle in which the group fits): `theGroup.getBBox()`.

This is returning an SVGRect object with the following properties: x, y, width, height. You can use those properties to build the value for the `viewBox` attribute: `viewBox = "x y width height"`

Comment: Hi, It worked great, How can set the size of the svg?i want to make the above svg smaller in size

Comment: @AshokThangarajan I've updated my answer. Please take a look.